# Liquid templating : Parsing String value to objects and using as a variable

Tags: liquid

I'd like to give content editors a way to specify a gallery they'd like to use. Now, the input is retrieved as string, which, when stored into a variable intended to use as an object doesn't work. Please see the code below that works:

```
{% assign pagehandle = site.galleries.projects %}

<div class="section thumbs-grid" aria-hidden="true">
  {% for image in pagehandle.images %}
     <img src="{{ image | gallery_asset_url }}"/>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The value I retrieve from the user input is stored as string, hence as below:

```
{{ page.user-input }} // Outputs site.galleries.projects

{% assign pagehandle = page.user-input %} // Probably stored as string
```

The above variable does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"site.galleries.projects"` is a string. Printing this string will return nothing else than a string.

If you want to reach a property in `site.galleries` array/hash, you can use :

- dot notation : `site.galleries.projects`
- bracket notation with string : `site.galleries["project"]`
- bracket notation with variable : `site.galleries[myVar]` (no quotes, no curly braces)

This can work :

```
{{ page.user-input }} // Outputs string "**projects**"

{% assign pagehandle = site.galleries[page.user-input] %}
```

Comment: David, thanks for the prompt reply and yes, it works! Thanks very much! 
Would you mind explaining why the above code works and why mine didn't?

Comment: Edited my answer.